# How to test struct deallocation

Tags: c, unit-testing, free

I have an opaque struct along with allocation/deallocation functions in a header file. Here is it:

`my_strct.h`:

```
typedef struct helper helper;
helper *allocate_helper(void);
void release_helper(helper *helper_ptr);

typedef struct my_struct;
my_struct *allocate_mystruct(void);
void release_mystruct(my_struct *ptr);
```

`my_strct.c`:

```
#include "my_strct.h"

struct helper{
    const char *helper_info;
}

helper *allocate_helper(void){
     return malloc(sizeof(struct helper));
}

void release_helper(helper *helper_ptr){
     if(helper_ptr){
         free(helper_ptr -> helper_info);
         free(helper_ptr);
     }
}

struct my_struct{
     const char *info;
     const char *name;
     struct helper *helper_ptr
}

my_struct *allocate_mystruct(void){
    struct my_struct *mystruct_ptr = malloc(sizeof(mystruct_ptr));
    mystruct_ptr -> helper_ptr = allocate_helper(); 
}

void release_mystruct(struct my_struct *mystruct_ptr){
    if(mystruct_ptr){
        release_helper(mystruct_ptr -> helper_ptr);
        free(mystruct_ptr -> info);
        free(mystruct_ptr -> name);
        free(mystruct_ptr);
    }
}
```

The problem arose when I tried to write unit test for the `release_mystruct` deallocation function in order to make sure it does not cause memory leak. We cannot simply intercept all calls to `free` like we do in `Java` where I came from also redefining functions from standard library is undefined behavior.

Is there a way to approach the problem?

Comment: *"We cannot simply intercept all calls to `free`"* - How do you reckon Valgrind checks for leaks?

Comment: @StoryTeller Are you suggesting to run unit tests with Valgrind...? Or I musenderstood you?

Comment: I was commenting on the whole "can't intercept calls". You can if you know your library implementation. And writing tests that are meant to be ran under valgrind (or even better, run all the tests under valgrind from time to time) is a pretty good way to protect against all sorts of memory issues.

Comment: If in the rest code you don't dynamic allocate memory for strings `helper_info` `info` `name`, then you can't use `free` for this variables

Comment: @aragon I am aware that `free` can be called on the `m/re/c alloc`ed pointers. But would not it be a reasonable contract for a deallocation function to assume that it deallocates all memory it has pointers to now. If a client does not want some object to be deallocated it copies the pointer and sets a member pointer to `NULL`... ?

Comment: If you call free on a NULL it will do nothing. So your client can assign NULL to any pointer and free will neither try to free it nor will it raise an error.

Comment: @user6556709 But what's wrong with that? If client does not allocate memory for any object the containing object will keep holding `NULL` pointers so free does `nothing`. If a client allocates and assigns some valid pointer then releasing containing object will release the object as well. If client wants to take ownership of some subobject of the containing object it sets a member pointer to `NULL` and then deallocates it by themselves. What's wrong with such an approach?

Comment: Your pointers are not guaranteed to be NULL on start. You have to explicitly assign NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't. free doesn't give any hints if it worked as expected or not but the C standard guarantees that it will release the memory if you call it and the pointer exists. So you don't need to check for that.

If you want to check if the free is called you can assign NULL after the free and check on that.